# Formatting the number field in SQL for Reporting

Tags: sql, excel, formatting, reporting, phone-number

Currently I have a table which stores the customers details, however the phone number field are inputted in differently in the table:

```
ID | Name |Address |DOB         | Gender |Phone Number   |
---------------------------------------------------------
01 | Max  |Abc Road| 2000-12-19 | Male   |07777 893 8902 |
02 | Sam  |TBH Road| null       | Male   |077778938902   |
03 | Doe  |Dr  Road| 1999-11-13 | Male   |077778 938902  |
```

However is it possible to reformat the phone number field so that the results may appear as so:

```
ID | Name |Address |DOB         | Gender |Phone Number   |
---------------------------------------------------------
01 | Max  |Abc Road| 2000-12-19 | Male   |07777 893 8902 |
02 | Sam  |TBH Road| null       | Male   |07777 893 8902 |
03 | Doe  |Dr  Road| 1999-11-13 | Male   |07777 893 8902 |
```

Also for reporting and exporting reasons is it possible to ensure the 0 in the front of the phone number appears?

Any help is much appreciated - thanks :)

Comment: First of all, tell us what type of database you're connecting to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @TmpTbl TABLE (PhoneNumber varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @TmpTbl
SELECT
    '07777 893 8902' 
    UNION ALL SELECT '077778938902'
    UNION ALL SELECT '077778 938902'

select
CONCAT(LEFT(replace(PhoneNumber,' ',''),5)
       ,' '
       ,SUBSTRING(replace(PhoneNumber,' ',''),6,3)
       ,' '
       ,RIGHT(replace(PhoneNumber,' ',''),4))
from @TmpTbl
```

OR this will work as well in place of the CONCAT statement

```
Stuff(Stuff(REPLACE(PhoneNumber,' ',''),9,0,' '),6,0,' ')
```

Output:

```
07777 893 8902
07777 893 8902
07777 893 8902
```

Comment: perfect! You beat me to it.